# Creating a static lookup table when the integer type is Boost multiprecision number/cpp_int

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, gmp, boost-multiprecision

I'd like to create a static lookup table for powers of ten returned as type boost::mulitprecision's `uint256_t`:

```
static uint256_t power_ten(const uint8_t n)
{
    static const uint256_t table[] = 
    { 
        1,
        10
        // etc
    };

    return table[n];
}
```

However, I won't be able to define the literals for 256 bits because C++ literals are `int`s.

Consequently I thought I could use template metaprogramming to calculate the powers so I don't need to specify literals, similar to this Fibonacci example I found:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

using Integer = int;            // Works
//using Integer = uint256_t;    // Causes compiler errors

template<Integer n>
struct fibonacci
{
  static constexpr Integer value = fibonacci<n-1>::value + fibonacci<n-2>::value;
};

template<>
struct fibonacci<0>
{
  static constexpr Integer value = 0;
};

template<>
struct fibonacci<1>
{
  static constexpr Integer value = 1;
};

int main()
{   
    Integer a = fibonacci<40>::value;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

This code works for `int`. However, if I comment/uncomment to use `uint256_t` I get these compiler errors:

```
clang-14: warning: -lquadmath: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
<source>:8:18: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'Integer' (aka 'number<cpp_int_backend<256, 256, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void>>')
template<Integer n>
                 ^
<source>:11:28: error: declaration of constexpr static data member 'value' requires an initializer
  static constexpr Integer value = fibonacci<n-1>::value + fibonacci<n-2>::value;
                           ^
2 errors generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:8:18: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'Integer' (aka 'number<cpp_int_backend<256, 256, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void>>')
template<Integer n>
                 ^
<source>:11:28: error: declaration of constexpr static data member 'value' requires an initializer
  static constexpr Integer value = fibonacci<n-1>::value + fibonacci<n-2>::value;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qsK8rG5WG

Is there another way to achieve this?

UPDATE

I've just tried populating the static table using `uint256_t` with a string constructor, as per the comments. This seemed to work but once I reach:

```
uint256_t("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
```

`std::cout` outputs the wrong value:

```
73663286101470436611432119930496737173840122674875487684339327936694962880512
```

Comment: You should use the first method, there should be a specific literal definition method for `boost::mulitprecision`, such as using a string to define.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It works up to `uint256_t("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")` but then after this `cout` outputs wrong value? I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Then how can a **256-bits** integer hold such a large number?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Forgive me, i was confusing 256 with 512, which allows ~155 digits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using costly string initialization, consider an expression that is likely to be more efficient:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a18303c4686a2d91)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using boost::multiprecision::uint512_t;

static uint512_t power_ten(const uint8_t n)
{
    static const uint512_t table[] = {
        pow(uint512_t(10), 0),   pow(uint512_t(10), 1),  pow(uint512_t(10), 2),  pow(uint512_t(10), 3),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 4),   pow(uint512_t(10), 5),  pow(uint512_t(10), 6),  pow(uint512_t(10), 7),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 8),   pow(uint512_t(10), 9),  pow(uint512_t(10), 10), pow(uint512_t(10), 11),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 12),  pow(uint512_t(10), 13), pow(uint512_t(10), 14), pow(uint512_t(10), 15),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 16),  pow(uint512_t(10), 17), pow(uint512_t(10), 18), pow(uint512_t(10), 19),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 20),  pow(uint512_t(10), 21), pow(uint512_t(10), 22), pow(uint512_t(10), 23),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 24),  pow(uint512_t(10), 25), pow(uint512_t(10), 26), pow(uint512_t(10), 27),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 28),  pow(uint512_t(10), 29), pow(uint512_t(10), 30), pow(uint512_t(10), 31),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 32),  pow(uint512_t(10), 33), pow(uint512_t(10), 34), pow(uint512_t(10), 35),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 36),  pow(uint512_t(10), 37), pow(uint512_t(10), 38), pow(uint512_t(10), 39),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 40),  pow(uint512_t(10), 41), pow(uint512_t(10), 42), pow(uint512_t(10), 43),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 44),  pow(uint512_t(10), 45), pow(uint512_t(10), 46), pow(uint512_t(10), 47),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 48),  pow(uint512_t(10), 49), pow(uint512_t(10), 50), pow(uint512_t(10), 51),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 52),  pow(uint512_t(10), 53), pow(uint512_t(10), 54), pow(uint512_t(10), 55),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 56),  pow(uint512_t(10), 57), pow(uint512_t(10), 58), pow(uint512_t(10), 59),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 60),  pow(uint512_t(10), 61), pow(uint512_t(10), 62), pow(uint512_t(10), 63),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 64),  pow(uint512_t(10), 65), pow(uint512_t(10), 66), pow(uint512_t(10), 67),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 68),  pow(uint512_t(10), 69), pow(uint512_t(10), 70), pow(uint512_t(10), 71),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 72),  pow(uint512_t(10), 73), pow(uint512_t(10), 74), pow(uint512_t(10), 75),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 76),  pow(uint512_t(10), 77), pow(uint512_t(10), 78), pow(uint512_t(10), 79),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 80),  pow(uint512_t(10), 81), pow(uint512_t(10), 82), pow(uint512_t(10), 83),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 84),  pow(uint512_t(10), 85), pow(uint512_t(10), 86), pow(uint512_t(10), 87),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 88),  pow(uint512_t(10), 89), pow(uint512_t(10), 90), pow(uint512_t(10), 91),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 92),  pow(uint512_t(10), 93), pow(uint512_t(10), 94), pow(uint512_t(10), 95),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 96),  pow(uint512_t(10), 97), pow(uint512_t(10), 98), pow(uint512_t(10), 99),
        pow(uint512_t(10), 100),
        // etc
    };

    return table[n];
}

int main() {
    for (auto n = 0; n<100; ++n) 
        std::cout << power_ten(n) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
...
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

### Bonus

Even cleaner, make it procedural:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/569dabe87bd305dd)**

```
static uint512_t power_ten(const uint8_t n) {
    static auto const table = [] {
        std::array<uint512_t, 155> tmp;
        for(int exp = 0; auto& el : tmp)
            el = pow(uint512_t(10), exp++);
        return tmp;
    }();

    return table.at(n); // or [n]
}
```

Printing the same and more.

Comment: I suggest the procedural approach: it is much less error-prone, and does bounds checking.

Comment: Thanks! I've templated your function on `TYPE` and included cmath but Clang 14 is giving me `error: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'std::array<long, 150>::value_type' (aka 'long') [-Werror,-Wfloat-conversion]
                el = pow(TYPE(10), exp++);`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/1svrh1K3Y

Comment: Safe to static_cast the result from pow?

Comment: @intrigued_66 "safe"? Yes, here it seems - but you loose overflow checking. I'd avoid it. The problem is that [`std::pow` doesn't have integer overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). Therefore if you (now) also wanted to support primitive integral types I'd rephrase as follows: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d2dd44b682426bc (or https://godbolt.org/z/M9aGv9W8e)